# Как на чистом C записать следующую формулу

Tags: c

(1-tg x)^(ctg x)+ cos(x-y)

^ это возведение в степень

Comment: тут куча языков в тегах

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pow(1-tan(x),1/tan(x))+cos(x-y)
```